# Docker CPU contention with host processes

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have some processes that are run as docker containers and a few that runs directly in the host. Actually one of these host process also starts others docker containers. So, moving everything to docker and running docker inside docker is not something I want to do.

During heavy load when a number of docker containers are started, they eventually take 100% of cpu, leaving almost nothing for the host processes. Even the host process that were supposed to kill these containers couldn't run.

Is it possible to restrict the total CPU usage for all the docker containers, to something like 90%, so even in heavy load the host processes get 10% cpu?

Setting cpu shared doesn't help, because they are only relative weights for all docker containers. They don't leave anything for the host.

Setting cpu quota is suboptimal, they either lead to under utilization when there is low usage, and still doesn't stop when the load is heavy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, with various options I have used. Elysian Fields's answer was one of the simplest and works reliably. There are a few other options, I am now using in combination.

1. --cpuset-cpus: On a machine with 4 cpus (0-3), I can reserve a 1 CPU exclusively for the host processes by starting all container with --cpuset-cpus=1-3 (That is 0 reserved for host processes)
2. --cpu-quota/--cpu-period: Can be used to limit the containers CPU time share. For example, --cpu-quota=10000 --cpu-period=100000 (limits CPU usage to 10ms every 100ms). However, this won't work if you start more than certain number of containers, in this example 10. Also, when there are no other processes, the CPU 
   will be wasted.
3. Start the process with **nice** if it is included in the image. The nice command should be run within the container. For example,
   `docker run openjdk:10-slim nice -n5 java HelloWorld` So the important host process always gets higher priority compared to these container tasks. (The priority can be lowered upto 19(lowest). If you want to increase the priority of the process within docker container, add `--cap-add=sys_nice` to docker command)

Answer (score 1):

You can't limit the load in this fashion if you are running natively.

If you are using a virtual machine (such as running on OSX or Windows) you can limit this through the VM settings, but otherwise there's not really any way to effectively do this with docker.

However, if you want to restrict the total number of CPUs available for the machine, you can try `--cpuset` ([doc link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/runtime-constraints-on-resources)) which lets you specify the total number of available CPUs for the container.

Depending on your situation, you might be able to make this work - if you run on a 4 core machine, you could allocate 3 to the container and leave 1 to the host. It's still sort of inefficient, but perhaps good enough for your situation.

From the docs:

```
$ docker run -it --cpuset-cpus="1,3" ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

But I'm not sure this will be any better if you are already finding the cpu quota option to be limiting.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon the last answer, the number of cpu's dedicated to docker can be seen in advanced settings (in windows version).

[image]